# How to overide internet website using local Apache2 hosted website?

Tags: networking, apache2

I have set up a website (www.test.com) using Apache2 on Ubuntu 14.04.

However I can only access the website after disabling the network connection (using nmcli nm enable false). If I keep the network connection, Firefox always opens the internet version of it.

How can I make my site a higher priority than the internet version with network connected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to approach the problem, but the easy method is to edit your `/etc/hosts` file to make `www.test.com` map to local addresses instead.

1. In the Terminal, run the following: `sudo nano /etc/hosts`
2. Add a line in the following format: `127.0.0.1  www.test.com test.com`
3. Exit text editor
4. Nuke your browser cache (this means, delete all cached pages in your browser).
5. Try the site, it should load the local variant.

Comment: Ehheheh this answer was posted from my phone, and Sledge and I seem to have posted the same thing within a short time of each other xD

Answer (score 2):

You have to add it inside the hosts file, which is located in /etc.
Open it with your favorite console text editor (with root privileges by adding sudo in front of the command) and add the following text on a new line

```
127.0.0.1 test.com www.test.com
```

For example if you use mcedit the command will be:

```
sudo mcedit /etc/hosts
```

This assumes that apache is also running on the local interface (as it is by default). If you have disabled this functionality, you have to change `127.0.0.1` with the IP address apache is working on.

You can test  if everything works correctly with the ping command `ping test.com`